# How to list all my Fanpages in one page

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I want to do a list of all of my Facebook fanpages.

I want to do something like this : http://www.facebook.com/BRAVO

Any idea ?

Thx

Steve

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an application tab and add it to your page

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/) the documentation to start

Comment: Hi,
how I can get all of my Fan Pages in one page?